# Swift 3 tableviews with detailVC

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i'm practising structs and tableviews, it was fun until got stuck. I have 4 car companies in first tableview, (audi, bmw, mercedes, opel) then when clicked on one car company, i get years to choose, 2015, 2014 and so on, every year should have a set of different cars (manufactured in that year), but i get same cars in every year (audi1, audi2, audi3, audi4), and when clicked on different company i got separate years for every company , that is working. So, where to put array and how for 2014 to show audi5, audi6, audi7, AUDI8. And when clicked on car, it should display text and image in detailVC of that car, that is all working without tableview with years, i manage to do it with 2 tableviews with detailvc, but now trying with extra tableview, (years) and got stuck.

FirstTableViewcontroller

```
Import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var firstArray = [String]()
var secondArray = [FirstStruct]()
var thirdArray = [SecondStruct]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    firstArray = ["Audi", "Bmw", "Mercedes", "Opel"]

    secondArray = [FirstStruct(secondTitle: ["2015", "2014"]),
        FirstStruct(secondTitle: ["2015", "2014"]),
        FirstStruct(secondTitle: ["2015", "2014"]),
        FirstStruct(secondTitle: ["2015", "2014"])]

    thirdArray = [SecondStruct(thirdTitle: ["Audi 1", "Audi 2", "Audi 3", "Audi 4"]),
        SecondStruct(thirdTitle: ["Bmw1", "Bmw2", "Bmw3", "Bmw4"]),
        SecondStruct(thirdTitle: ["Mercedes1", "Mercedes2", "Mercedes3", "Mercedes4"]),
        SecondStruct(thirdTitle: ["Opel 1", "Opel 2", "Opel 3", "Opel 4"])]

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return firstArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = firstArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

    let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondTableViewController

    let join : FirstStruct
    join = secondArray[indexPath.row]

    destVC.firstArray = join.secondTitle

    let join2 : SecondStruct
    join2 = thirdArray[indexPath.row]

    destVC.secondArray = join2.thirdTitle


}
}
```

Secondtableviewcontroller

```
import UIKit

class SecondTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var firstArray = [String]()
var secondArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return firstArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = firstArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    //let indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

    let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ThirdTableViewController

    //let divide = secondArray[indexPath.row]
    destVC.firstArray = secondArray


}
}
}
```

ThirdTableViewController

```
import UIKit

class ThirdTableViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var firstArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return firstArray.count

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = firstArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: Your statement is too hard to understand. If all works fine before you added the third VC, then just pass all data you need from the 2nd VC to the 3rd VC, and then DetailVC. One comment on your code is, it's good practise to name your classes and variables in a meaningful way. Like SecondtableViewController should be something like ChooseYearTableViewController.

Comment: i tried that but no go, when i click on 2015 or 2104 i got audi1, audi2, audi3, audi4 displayed, and i want to be displayed audi5, audi6 when clicked on 2014,  where should i type audi5, audi6 for 2014 to display that?

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you need to implement the tableView:didSelectCell method, then based the cell you selected, you can pass different data to the next VC.